# I keep hearing there are tons of bug trackers, but not so many build in .net

Tags: .net, bug-tracking

Yes there are tons of bug trackor applications to buy, but being a .net shop, and always leaning towards purchasing .net build products, I don't see that many options when it comes to bug trackers.

From the top of my head I can only think of 2, axosoft and gemini.

What else is out there?

Am I alone here or do most other .net shops want .net build products?

Answer (score 17):

It couldn't matter less to me what technology the bug tracker is built in.  I like FogBugz alot, and it's not .Net based.  Neither is Bugzilla, and we've used that to track .Net projects.

There's really no point in worrying about the underlying technology of the tools you need to do your job right.

Comment: The latest release of FogBugz is .Net.

Answer (score 3):

Several of the other answers say that it doesn't matter what the system is written in, and i can't agree with that.

They are probably right when it comes to simple desktop applications (for example, we use Mercurial/TortoiseHG for source control and it **really** doesn't matter that it's written in Python...it just works).

But it's completely different when the application needs some kind of special server (web server, database server...most available bug trackers need both).
When you need some of those, you will probably use something you know:

For example, we are a Microsoft shop...we already have ASP.NET web servers and SQL servers ready and running and we have people who know how to use them.
On the other hand, there's no one here who knows anything about, say, Oracle/MySql/PostgreSql or Ruby/PHP.

This rules out quite a lot of the available bug trackers because we have no idea to even get them to run!

Yes, we could try & error and setup new web and database servers and try to get the stuff working, but it's hard to justify learning all the stuff just to run a simple bug tracker.
(and just installing and getting it to run is not all you need...for example, when you have the database running, someone has to figure out how to take backups, how to restore them in case something goes wrong...the list goes on and on)

So we will probably use a .net bug tracker (we are just evaluating ourselves)...probably Bugtracker.Net.

**EDIT:**

John, that's not what I meant.

For example, besides Bugtracker.Net I evaluated Redmine as well (which is written in Ruby on Rails).
I don't want to change anything in the Redmine code, just install it - but take a look at the [installation instructions](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/RedmineInstall):
Even to get Redmine installed, you need a certain level of knowledge about RoR (which I don't have at all, neither any of my co-workers - we are Windows and .net users and no one of us has ever used Ruby).
Maybe Redmine is cooler than BugTracker.Net or can do more - but can we really justify learning some RoR just to be able to install this one piece of software?

Comment: You don't need to know how PHP or Java work to _run_ such things. Of course if you want to be able to make custom changes in the code it's a different story.

Comment: I edited my answer - see above!

Comment: Where I am currently is a Microsoft shop and we use Trac, and at a previous place (also Microsoft only) we used Mantis.

Comment: The main problem with most software is that they don't provide a simple install (like say CollabNet Subversion Edge for subversion) that could be installed independently of everthing. RoR based applications are a pain in the ass and Trac is not really better (dependencies to be installed manually, depends on a specific mod python version, itself depending on a specific apache version...). But .Net app aren't better at all... yeah ok for 3 tables you want me to manage a full SQL Server instance... and install on a server version of windows...

Comment: I disagree with this answer.  It sounds like your conclusion is "products written in a language you don't understand will have hard-to-follow installation instructions", which is of course rubbish.  I completely agree that the ease-of-use and quality of documentation is a major factor, but to make a sweeping correlation between these things, and the implementation language, is quite frankly silly.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [BugNet](http://www.bugnetproject.com/), which is .NET based, actually it appears to be based on an older version of DotNetNuke.

It isn't perfect, but it works.  You can see my styled version [here](http://productsupport.iowacomputergurus.com).

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's always [BugTracker.NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html)...

Personally, i don't really care what the system is written in. So long as it isn't Classic ASP. Ew.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try EzSDLC  http://encodesoft.com/?page_id=77 , they provide screenshot pdf as well. The tool is .NET based

Answer (score 0):

You forgot FogBugz.  I don't think it's entirely in .net but parts of it definitely is.

Also I am the same when looking for open source options.  I look for .net products first because I know how they work.  With closed source options or hosted options I don't care much.

Comment: I thought FB used their own .net language Wasabi, does this count? However if you're using a closed source solution, who cares what it's written in as long as it doesn't force you into licensing software you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

This Issue Tracker application from Microsoft can also be used: [http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived/starter-kits/issue-tracker/]

Answer (score 0):

Parts of [Fortress](http://www.sourcegear.com) were built in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been tasked with getting an open source bug tracking system up for my company. I looked through many of the commercial and open source systems available and finally settled on [BugTracker .NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html), which is free.

I am definitely happy with my decision. The system is very feature rich, especially in the email notifications area. But the part that I like about it the most is it's flexibility. My bosses wanted tons of different changes done to it when I first demoed the app to them. Amazingly 99% of the changes didn't require me to write any code, they were either settings in the admin config or the web.config. And for the coding modifications I did make I can say the app's code is certainly understandable and isn't too hard to modify if you need to (which you probably won't).