# how to configure a rails app (redmine) to run as a service on windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, service, redmine

I'm using redmine as a ticket manager, and I'd like to configure it to be run automatically when windows starts up.

How can I configure it to be run as a service?

--

Just asked the question to document it, I hope somebody may find it useful...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**1. using webrick:**

ref: http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/4123

- Download and install the Windows NT Resource Kit from
  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en
- Create the service by running this command:

  ```
  path\INSTSRV.EXE your_service_name path\SRVANY.EXE
  ```

  in my case `path` is:

  ```
  "C:\Program Files\Windows NT Resource Kit\INSTSRV.EXE" redmine_webrick "C:\Program Files\Windows NT Resource Kit\SRVANY.EXE"
  ```

  could be also `C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\`.
- Run regedit (Start -> Run -> regedit)

  - Add the following registry key if it's not already there:

    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\your_service_name
  - Right click on this registry key and select New -> Key. Name it `Parameters`.
  - Add two values to the `Parameters` key. Right click on the parameters key, New -> String Value. Name it `Application`. Now create another one named `AppParameters`. Give them the following values:

    - Application: `PathToRuby.exe`, eg. `C:\ruby\bin\Ruby.exe`
    - AppParameters: `C:\RUBYAPP\script\server -e production`, where `RUBYAPP` is the directory that contains the redmine website.

    Example: `C:\redmine\script\server -p 2000 -e production` (-p indicates the port webrick will be listening to, and -e the environment used)

Now you can go to Administrative Tools -> Services. There you can start your service (the one with name `your_service_name`) and test whether or not it is working properly. It should be noted that the service will be marked as started prior to WEBrick finishing its boot procedure. You should give it 1min or so before trying to hit the service to verify that it is working correctly.

**2. using mongrel:**

ref: http://mongrel.rubyforge.org/wiki
ref: http://mongrel.rubyforge.org/wiki/Win32

first install mongrel and mongrel_service gem

```
gem install mongrel

gem install mongrel_service
```

then create the service

```
mongrel_rails service::install -N redmine_mongrel -c c:\redmine -p 3000 -e production
```

**3. using thin:**

References:

- http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/
- http://www.astarbe.com/es/trucos/windows/srvany_convierte_una_aplicacion_en_servicio

Instructions:

1. First install thin (you'll need to install rack gem, if not already
   installed)

   ```
   gem install rack     
   gem install thin
   ```
2. Follow the same steps indicated for webrick, but add another value named "AppDirectory". This is needed in order to avoid using c:\ruby\bin\thin.bat If I just pointed to the bat file, I couldn't stop the service.

   In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\redmine_thin\Parameters` add the following keys:

   > Application: c:\ruby\bin\ruby.exe
   >
   > AppDirectory: c:\redmine
   >
   > AppParameters: c:\ruby\bin\thin start -p 4000 -e production

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

You can control any of your service with the following commands:

> net start redmine_xxx
>
> net stop redmine_xxx
>
> sc config redmine_xxx start= auto
>
> sc config redmine_xxx start= auto dependency= MySql
>
> sc delete redmine_xxx

Comment: thanks! worked like a charm.  But I used rubyw.exe based on some stuff I was reading on a different thread.

Comment: In case of `rails 4` how would `C:\redmine\script\server -p 2000 -e production` command look like ?

Comment: I am using `puma` as the web server in a `rails 4.2.5` app. Any suggestion on how to configure it to run as a windows service?

Comment: Hi @wolfcall, sorry for the late reply. I remember that I was able to get it work with puma. I shared my answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38959731/5715870). This [README](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/README.md) also contains useful info. Hope it helps. 

Comment: @dhrubo_moy lol don't worry dude I got it working a few days later. Turns out was a rack issue. Had to down grade the version works just fine now.

Answer (score 4):

For Rails 3.0.x applications (tested on 3.0.10 & Windows 7)

demo_daemon_ctl.rb

```
############################################################################
# demo_daemon_ctl.rb
#
# This is a command line script for installing and/or running a small
# Ruby program as a service.  The service will simply write a small bit
# of text to a file every 20 seconds. It will also write some text to the
# file during the initialization (service_init) step.
#
# It should take about 10 seconds to start, which is intentional - it's a test
# of the service_init hook, so don't be surprised if you see "one moment,
# start pending" about 10 times on the command line.
#
# The file in question is C:\test.log.  Feel free to delete it when finished.
#
# To run the service, you must install it first.
#
# Usage: ruby demo_daemon_ctl.rb <option>
#
# Note that you *must* pass this program an option
#
# Options:
#    install    - Installs the service.  The service name is "DemoSvc"
#                 and the display name is "Demo".
#    start      - Starts the service.  Make sure you stop it at some point or
#                 you will eventually fill up your filesystem!.
#    stop       - Stops the service.
#    pause      - Pauses the service.
#    resume     - Resumes the service.
#    uninstall  - Uninstalls the service.
#    delete     - Same as uninstall.
#
# You can also used the Windows Services GUI to start and stop the service.
#
# To get to the Windows Services GUI just follow:
#    Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services
############################################################################
require 'win32/service'
require 'rbconfig'
include Win32
include Config

# Make sure you're using the version you think you're using.
puts 'VERSION: ' + Service::VERSION

SERVICE_NAME = 'DemoSvc'
SERVICE_DISPLAYNAME = 'Demo'

# Quote the full path to deal with possible spaces in the path name.
ruby = File.join(CONFIG['bindir'], 'ruby').tr('/', '\\')
path = ' "' + File.dirname(File.expand_path($0)).tr('/', '\\')
path += '\demo_daemon.rb"'
cmd = ruby + path

# You must provide at least one argument.
raise ArgumentError, 'No argument provided' unless ARGV[0]

case ARGV[0].downcase
     when 'install'
            Service.new(
                 :service_name     => SERVICE_NAME,
                 :display_name     => SERVICE_DISPLAYNAME,
                 :description      => 'Sample Ruby service',
                 :binary_path_name => cmd
            )
            puts 'Service ' + SERVICE_NAME + ' installed'      
     when 'start' 
            if Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state != 'running'
                 Service.start(SERVICE_NAME, nil, 'hello', 'world')
                 while Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state != 'running'
                        puts 'One moment...' + Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state
                        sleep 1
                 end
                 puts 'Service ' + SERVICE_NAME + ' started'
            else
                 puts 'Already running'
            end
     when 'stop'
            if Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state != 'stopped'
                 Service.stop(SERVICE_NAME)
                 while Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state != 'stopped'
                        puts 'One moment...' + Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state
                        sleep 1
                 end
                 puts 'Service ' + SERVICE_NAME + ' stopped'
            else
                 puts 'Already stopped'
            end
     when 'uninstall', 'delete'
            if Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state != 'stopped'
                 Service.stop(SERVICE_NAME)
            end
            while Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state != 'stopped'
                 puts 'One moment...' + Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state
                 sleep 1
            end
            Service.delete(SERVICE_NAME)
            puts 'Service ' + SERVICE_NAME + ' deleted'
     when 'pause'
            if Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state != 'paused'
                 Service.pause(SERVICE_NAME)
                 while Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state != 'paused'
                        puts 'One moment...' + Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state
                        sleep 1
                 end
                 puts 'Service ' + SERVICE_NAME + ' paused'
            else
                 puts 'Already paused'
            end
     when 'resume'
            if Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state != 'running'
                 Service.resume(SERVICE_NAME)
                 while Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state != 'running'
                        puts 'One moment...' + Service.status(SERVICE_NAME).current_state
                        sleep 1
                 end
                 puts 'Service ' + SERVICE_NAME + ' resumed'
            else
                 puts 'Already running'
            end
     else
            raise ArgumentError, 'unknown option: ' + ARGV[0]
end
```

demo_daemon.rb

```
APP_ROOT_CUSTOM = 'your app root dir'
LOG_FILE = APP_ROOT_CUSTOM + 'log/win32_daemon_test.log'
APP_PATH = File.expand_path( APP_ROOT_CUSTOM  + 'config/application', APP_ROOT_CUSTOM  + 'script/rails')

begin  
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'win32/daemon'
    include Win32
    require File.expand_path( APP_ROOT_CUSTOM  + 'config/boot', APP_ROOT_CUSTOM  + 'script/rails')
    require 'rails/commands/server'
    module ::Rails
        class Server
            def default_options
                super.merge({
                    :Port        => 3000,
                    :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development").dup,
                    :daemonize   => false,
                    :debugger    => false,
                    :pid         => File.expand_path( APP_ROOT_CUSTOM + "tmp/pids/server.pid" ),
                    :config      => File.expand_path( APP_ROOT_CUSTOM + "config.ru" )
                })
            end
        end
    end

    class DemoDaemon < Daemon       
        # This method fires off before the +service_main+ mainloop is entered.
        # Any pre-setup code you need to run before your service's mainloop
        # starts should be put here. Otherwise the service might fail with a
        # timeout error when you try to start it.
        #
        def service_init
        end

        # This is the daemon's mainloop. In other words, whatever runs here
        # is the code that runs while your service is running. Note that the
        # loop is not implicit.
        #
        # You must setup a loop as I've done here with the 'while running?'
        # code, or setup your own loop. Otherwise your service will exit and
        # won't be especially useful.
        #
        # In this particular case, I've setup a loop to append a short message
        # and timestamp to a file on your C: drive every 20 seconds. Be sure
        # to stop the service when you're done!
        #
        def service_main(*args)

            Rails::Server.new.tap { |server|
                require APP_PATH
                Dir.chdir( APP_ROOT_CUSTOM )
                server.start
            }

            msg = 'application started at: ' + Time.now.to_s

            File.open(LOG_FILE, 'a'){ |f|
                f.puts msg
                f.puts "Args: " + args.join(',')
            }

            # While we're in here the daemon is running.
            while running?
                if state == RUNNING
                    sleep 20 
                    msg = 'Service is running as of: ' + Time.now.to_s
                    File.open(LOG_FILE, 'a'){ |f| f.puts msg }
                else # PAUSED or IDLE
                    sleep 0.5
                end
            end

            # We've left the loop, the daemon is about to exit.

            File.open(LOG_FILE, 'a'){ |f| f.puts "STATE: #{state}" }

            msg = 'service_main left at: ' + Time.now.to_s

            File.open(LOG_FILE, 'a'){ |f| f.puts msg }
        end

        # This event triggers when the service receives a signal to stop. I've
        # added an explicit "exit!" here to ensure that the Ruby interpreter exits
        # properly. I use 'exit!' instead of 'exit' because otherwise Ruby will
        # raise a SystemExitError, which I don't want.
        #
        def service_stop
            msg = 'Received stop signal at: ' + Time.now.to_s
            File.open(LOG_FILE, 'a'){ |f| f.puts msg }
            exit!
        end

        # This event triggers when the service receives a signal to pause. 
        #
        def service_pause
            msg = 'Received pause signal at: ' + Time.now.to_s
            File.open(LOG_FILE, 'a'){ |f| f.puts msg }
        end

        # This event triggers when the service receives a signal to resume
        # from a paused state.
        #
        def service_resume
            msg = 'Received resume signal at: ' + Time.now.to_s
            File.open(LOG_FILE, 'a'){ |f| f.puts msg }
        end
    end

    # Create an instance of the Daemon and put it into a loop. I borrowed the
    # method name 'mainloop' from Tk, btw.
    #
    DemoDaemon.mainloop
rescue Exception => err
    File.open(LOG_FILE, 'a'){ |fh| fh.puts 'Daemon failure: ' + err }
    raise
end
```

place both files in same dir and run

```
ruby demo_daemon_ctl.rb install
```

Comment: I don't remember where I found code that I used as a base for daemon.

Comment: There are pretty much things to customize from service name to custom logging.

Answer (score 2):

use http://www.firedaemon.com/

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help to anyone. I defined the windows service that starts the redmine with the thin server.

Use http://nssm.cc/usage for windows service creation. Set the path to ruby.exe, your redmine's working directory and define the starting parameters:

```
Path: C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\bin\ruby.exe
Startup directory: C:\Program Files\redmine-3.4.6
Arguments: C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\bin\thin start -e production -p 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I tried to install Redmine on Windows as well. But I wasn't able to get it to work, probably [because of lack of Rails knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3254490/6884).

Then I discovered [Bitnami Redmine Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/redmine). They have a Windows installer, which installs Redmine with all needed dependencies, **and it just works**.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 4.0.x applications as suggested by Bohdan,
we have to replace

CONFIG['bindir'] with RbConfig::CONFIG['bindir']

Remmber to:
gem install win32-service

Answer (score 0):

- `gem install win32-service`
- drop below Ruby code in a service.rb file and update REDMINE_DIR path to fit your Redmine installation
- create the service, for example with `sc create redmine binPath= "C:\Ruby23-x64\bin\rubyw -C E:\www\redmine-3.3.2\ service.rb"` where `E:\www\redmine-3.3.2\` is the path of the directory where the service.rb file is located and `C:\Ruby23-x64\bin\rubyw` your Ruby installation path

begin
      require 'win32/daemon'
      include Win32

```
  class RedmineService < Daemon

    def service_init
      File.open(LOG_FILE, 'a'){ |f| f.puts "Initializing service #{Time.now}" } 

      #@server_pid = Process.spawn 'ruby script/rails s -e production', :chdir => REDMINE_DIR, :err => [LOG_FILE, 'a']
      # use full path
      @server_pid = Process.spawn 'C:\Ruby23-x64\bin\ruby E:\www\redmine-3.3.2\bin\rails s -e production -p 3000', :chdir => REDMINE_DIR, :err => [LOG_FILE, 'a']
    end

    def service_main
      File.open(LOG_FILE, 'a'){ |f| f.puts "Service is running #{Time.now} with pid #{@server_pid}" }
      while running?
        sleep 10
      end
    end

    def service_stop
      File.open(LOG_FILE, 'a'){ |f| f.puts "Stopping server thread #{Time.now}" }
      system "taskkill /PID #{@server_pid} /T /F" 
      Process.waitall
      File.open(LOG_FILE, 'a'){ |f| f.puts "Service stopped #{Time.now}" }
      exit!
    end
  end

  RedmineService.mainloop

rescue Exception => e
  File.open(LOG_FILE,'a+'){ |f| f.puts " ***Daemon failure #{Time.now} exception=#{e.inspect}\n#{e.backtrace.join($/)}" }
  raise
end
```

- Note that Process.spawn in the service.rb use the full path.