# Howto - Running Redmine on mongrel as a service on windows

Tags: windows, ruby, service, mongrel, redmine

I use Redmine on Mongrel as a project manager and I use a batch file (start-redmine.bat) to start the redmine in mongrel.
There are 2 issues with my setup:
1. I have a running IIS on the server that occupies the HTTP port (80)
2. The start-redmine.bat must be periodically checked to see if it's stopped after a restart that is caused by windows update service.

for the first issue, I have no choice but running mongrel on a port like 3000 and for the second issue I have to create a windows service that runs automatically in the background when the windows starts; and here comes the trouble!

There are at least 3 ways to run redmine as a service that I'm aware of; none of them can satisfy a performance view on this subject. you may read about them on 
[how to configure a rails app (redmine) to run as a service on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877943/how-to-configure-a-rails-app-redmine-to-run-as-a-service-on-windows)

I tried them all. The easiest way to setup such a service is using mongrel_service approach; in 3 lines of command you're done. but the performance is significantly lower than running that batch file...

---

*Now, I wanna show you my approach:*
First suppose we have ruby installed into **c:\ruby** and we have issued the command **gem install mongrel** to get the mongrel gem installed into **c:\ruby\bin**
Also, suppose we have installed the Redmine into a folder like **c:\redmine**; and we have ruby's path (i.e. *c:\ruby\bin*) in our PATH environment variable.

Now Download and install the Windows NT Resource Kit Tools from microsoft website.
Open the command-line tool that comes with the Resource Kit (from start menu).
Use instsrv to install a dummy service called Redmine using the following command:

> "[path-to-instsrv.exe]\instsrv" Redmine "[path-to-srvany.exe]\srvany.exe"

in my case (which is the default case) it was something like this:

> "C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\instsrv" Redmine "C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\srvany.exe"

Now create the batch file. Open a notepad and paste these instructions into it and then save it as "**c:\redmine\start-redmine.bat**"

> @echo off
>   cd  c:\redmine\
>   mongrel_rails start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e production

Now we need to configure that dummy service we had created before. **WATCH OUT WHAT YOU'RE DOING FROM HERE ON, OR YOU MAY CORRUPT YOUR WINDOWS**. To configure that service, open windows registry editor (Start -> Run -> regedit) and navigate to this node:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Redmine

Right-Click on "Redmine" node and using the context menu, create a new key called **Parameters** (New -> Key)
Right-Click on "Parameters" and create a String Value property called **Application**. Do this again and create another String Value called **AppParameters**.
Now Double-click on "Application" and put **cmd.exe** into "Value data" section. Then Double-click on "AppParameters" and put **/C "C:\redmine\start-redmine.bat"** into Value data section.

We're done!
issue this command to run the redmine on mongrel as a service:

> net start Redmine

Edit:
If you're gonna use the mail services of Redmine and you have an anti-virus like McAfee, make sure you told the anti-virus to allow ruby send emails or you won't get the mail service working.

Comment: Is there a question here? BTW What ruby version are you using? You should be using the versions from rubyinstaller.org. Weird that mongrel_service is slower, I deploy like that all the time. I also deploy using thin, but mongrel_service works nicer as a service.

Comment: There's no question. It's a HowTo, sharing what I learned after 3-4 hours of searching and thinking.
I'm a .Net developer and I'm not familiar with Ruby, It's installed lately by one of my friends and I think he's got the latest version available; but my approach to a mongrel service is significantly faster than a mongrel_service approach.

After all, I think I'm going to love this ruby thing! It's nice and smooth...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the guide! By the way, if you're running Windows 2008, use the prerelease version of the mongrel service or else it won't work for you:

gem install mongrel_service --prerelease

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/1adf2a73c75c2884/38267c06198e282e?show_docid=38267c06198e282e