# Run WEBrick as a Windows service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

How can you run WEBrick servers in the background as a Windows service? I tried following the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877943/how-to-configure-a-rails-app-redmine-to-run-as-a-service-on-windows) post, but I am using Rails 3, and couldn't come up with an equivalent to `C:\RUBYAPP\script\server -e production`, since the `server` directory doesn't exist in Rails 3 anymore. Any help?

Comment: Probably not a very helpful comment but I had the same problem a while back and had to give up because Mongrel didn't support services for Rails 3, end of the story. This might have changed but if you're having trouble chances are the problem still persists.

Comment: @pepe, I'm using WEBrick at the moment, not mongrel, for just that reason. I couldn't even get mongrel to run at all for me, let alone run as a service :/

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was reading too fast and I assumed you meant Mongrel since most people use it. I have never seen WEBrick used as a Windows service but I successful ran Mongrel manually. I have switched to Thin lately, though. If what you're looking for is to run the server automatically and you don't really care about it being a Windows service you could run it as a background job at start up.

Comment: Yeah, I realize WEBrick isn't normally used for production, but I am deploying to a very small pool of users (<5), and I have multiple WEBrick instances running behind Apache's load balancer proxy, so I'm not too worried about performance :P

But this background job thing sounds interesting... How would I go about doing that?

Comment: It's been a while since I tried it. I got a proof of concept at one point working, but it's been a while. I'll make a note to look into it tonight when I get home (I think I took some notes at the time) and will let you know tomorrow.

Comment: I looked around but couldn't find the notes, however I think I remember how to do it. You'll need a bat file with the 2 instructions to start the Mongrel server ('cd to_your_absolute_app_path' and 'rails s'). Then you'll need to convert that bat file to an exe file (check [this](http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e) for a free tool. I know the tool exists for 32 and 64 bits, you might need to look around for the right one). When you create the exe make sure to select it to run as an invisible app. Then you put the exe in the start up folder. I think that should do it.

Comment: That works great :) I think I'm going to create Windows services using the resulting exes just for easy restarting if anything ever crashes, but I can confirm that your solution works for me. I'll accept it if you post it :P Thanks!

Comment: Running these as a Windows service isn't possible :P The executables run just long enough to extract the .bat I wrote, and then it exits, so Windows thinks the service terminated. Oh well, the startup folder works for me :P

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do the same at the time with the same results. I don't understand the requirements of an executable to work as a Windows service and didn't have the time to look into it. I hope the startup folder option is all you need.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure either, but the startup folder works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen WEBrick used in Windows services but a workaround could be running the web server as a background job. This is how you would do it:

You'll need a bat file with the 2 instructions to start the web server:

- cd to_your_absolute_app_path
- rails s

Then you'll need to convert that bat file to an exe file. Check [this](http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e) for a free tool. I know the tool exists for 32 and 64 bits, you might need to look around for the right one.

When you create the exe make sure to select it to run as an invisible app.

Then you put the exe in the start up folder. That should do it.

Comment: Just FYI, I ended up using the tool you recommended in combination with [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/) (Non-Sucking Service Manager) to run the resulting exe as a Windows service.

Comment: As it turns out I am going to need to start Thin this way in a few weeks for a client so this comes in very handy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you have any questions about it :)

Comment: Excellent Job! Thank you very much.